# Timing execution of OpenCL kernels

Tags: c++, profiling, opencl

Is this a correct way of timing kernel execution time for OpenCL? I am quite keen on using the c++ wrapper (which unfortunately does not have many examples of timings).

```
cl::CommandQueue queue(context, device, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &err);
checkErr(err, "Cannot create the command queue");

/* Warm-up */
for (unsigned i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS; ++i)
{
    err = queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(512), cl::NullRange, NULL, NULL);
    checkErr(err, "Cannot enqueue the kernel");
}
queue.finish();

/* Time kernels */
cl::Event start, stop;
queue.enqueueMarker(&start);
for (unsigned i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS; ++i)
{
    err = queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(512), cl::NullRange, NULL, NULL);
    checkErr(err, "Cannot enqueue the kernel");
}
queue.enqueueMarker(&stop);

stop.wait();
cl_ulong time_start, time_end;
double total_time;
start.getProfilingInfo(CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, &time_start);
stop.getProfilingInfo(CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, &time_end);
total_time = time_end - time_start;

/* Results */
cout << "Execution time in milliseconds " << total_time / (float)10e6 / NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS << endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your approach should work just fine (is it not?).  Alternately, if you want to time each call, you can pass an event to `enqueueNDRangeKernel` and call `getProfilingInfo` on that `enqueueNDRangeKernel`.

```
cl::Event evt;
err = queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(512), cl::NullRange, NULL, &evt);
evt.wait();
elapsed += evt.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>() -
            evt.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>();
```