# What could be causing my vectorized kernels to slow down by such an absurd magnitude?

Tags: c++, opencl

I've written a program designed to test the performance of every single compute device registered with the OS. The Graphics Card is an AMD Radeon HD 5450. On my computer in particular, these are the four devices found:

- **Platform:** AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing

  - **Name:** Cedar
  - **Type:** GPU
- **Platform:** AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing

  - **Name:** Cedar
  - **Type:** GPU
  - *(apparently, the graphics card itself is listed twice? I dunno, I didn't build this thing...)*
- **Platform:** AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing

  - **Name:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
  - **Type:** CPU
- **Platform:** Experimental OpenCL 2.0 CPU Only Platform

  - **Name:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
  - **Type:** CPU

On Devices 0, 1, and 3, when executing the kernels listed below, they all vary significantly in terms of their overall speed, but nominally all finish within expected magnitudes of differences in terms of direct comparisons. I've put the results for the Intel CPU on the Intel Platform on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/RzwAthTV).

But with Device 2, not only is execution rather dramatically slower than the other devices (for only the integral types, I might add!) it's slower by absurd orders of magnitude, despite the fact that it's supposedly using the same device (the Intel CPU) as the Intel Platform is using, which has no such issues. [See this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/fmSTsXWx).

The notable outlying times (which are causing the massive slowdown) have to do with the vectorized versions of my code, and also depend on the code not being unary. Something about the AMD platform driving an Intel CPU seems very incompatible.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? I've included my full complete code below, in case it has anything to do with the underlying problem.

Executor.hpp

```
#pragma once
#define CL_HPP_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#include<CL\cl2.hpp>

class buffers {
    cl::Buffer a, b, c;
    cl::Buffer output;
    size_t size;

    template<typename T>
    buffers(cl::Context const& context, size_t size, T t) :
    size(size){
        std::vector<T> values;
        values.resize(size * 16);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            values[i] = T(i);
        a = cl::Buffer( context, values.begin(), values.end(), true );
        for (auto & val : values)
            val *= 3;
        b = cl::Buffer( context, values.begin(), values.end(), true );
        for (auto & val : values)
            val /= 10;
        c = cl::Buffer( context, values.begin(), values.end(), true );
        output = cl::Buffer( context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, size * 16 * sizeof(T) );
    }

public:
    template<typename T>
    static buffers make_buffer(cl::Context const& context, size_t size) {
        return buffers(context, size, T(0));
    }
    cl::Buffer get_a() const {
        return a;
    }

    cl::Buffer get_b() const {
        return b;
    }

    cl::Buffer get_c() const {
        return c;
    }

    cl::Buffer get_output() const {
        return output;
    }

    size_t get_size() const {
        return size;
    }
};
class task {
    cl::CommandQueue queue;
    cl::Kernel kernel;
    buffers * b;
    std::string type_name;
public:
    task(cl::CommandQueue queue, cl::Kernel kernel, buffers * b, std::string const& type_name) :
        queue(queue),
        kernel(kernel),
        b(b),
        type_name(type_name){
        int argc = kernel.getInfo<CL_KERNEL_NUM_ARGS>();
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            std::string something = kernel.getArgInfo<CL_KERNEL_ARG_NAME>(i);
            if(something == "a")
                kernel.setArg(i, b->get_a());
            else if(something == "b")
                kernel.setArg(i, b->get_b());
            else if(something == "c")
                kernel.setArg(i, b->get_c());
            else if(something == "output")
                kernel.setArg(i, b->get_output());
        }
    }

    cl::Event enqueue() {
        cl::Event event;
        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, {}, cl::NDRange{ b->get_size() }, {}, nullptr, &event);
        return event;
    }

    cl::Kernel get_kernel() const {
        return kernel;
    }

    std::string get_type_name() const {
        return type_name;
    }

    static std::chrono::nanoseconds time_event(cl::Event event) {
        event.wait();
        return std::chrono::nanoseconds{ event.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>() - event.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>() };
    }
};
```

TaskGenerator.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include "Executor.hpp"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

class kernel_generator {
public:
    static std::string get_primary_kernels() {
        return ""
#include "Primary Transform.cl"
#include "Transformations.cl"
#include "Transform Kernels.cl"
            ;
    }
    static std::string get_trigonometric_kernels() {
        return ""
#include "Trigonometry Transform.cl"
#include "Transformations.cl"
#include "Transform Kernels.cl"
            ;
    }
    static std::string get_utility_kernels() {
        return ""
#include "Utility Transform.cl"
#include "Transformations.cl"
#include "Transform Kernels.cl"
            ;
    }

private:
    static std::vector<cl::Kernel> get_kernels(std::string src, cl::Context context, cl::Device device, std::ostream & err_log) {
        try {
            cl::Program program{ context, src, false };
            program.build();
            std::vector<cl::Kernel> kernels;
            program.createKernels(&kernels);
            return kernels;
        }
        catch (cl::BuildError const& e) {
            std::cerr << "Unable to build kernels for " << device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << std::endl;
            err_log << "Build Log:\n";
            auto log = e.getBuildLog();
            for (auto const& log_p : log) {
                err_log << log_p.second << "\n";
            }
            return{};
        }
    }
public:
    static std::vector<cl::Kernel> get_char_kernels(cl::Context context, cl::Device device, std::ostream & err_log) {
        std::string src = ""
#include "char_defines.cl"
            + get_primary_kernels();
        return get_kernels(src, context, device, err_log);
    }
    static std::vector<cl::Kernel> get_short_kernels(cl::Context context, cl::Device device, std::ostream & err_log) {
        std::string src = ""
#include "short_defines.cl"
            + get_primary_kernels();
        return get_kernels(src, context, device, err_log);
    }
    static std::vector<cl::Kernel> get_int_kernels(cl::Context context, cl::Device device, std::ostream & err_log) {
        std::string src = ""
#include "int_defines.cl"
            + get_primary_kernels();
        return get_kernels(src, context, device, err_log);
    }
    static std::vector<cl::Kernel> get_long_kernels(cl::Context context, cl::Device device, std::ostream & err_log) {
        std::string src = ""
#include "long_defines.cl"
            + get_primary_kernels();
        return get_kernels(src, context, device, err_log);
    }
    static std::vector<cl::Kernel> get_float_kernels(cl::Context context, cl::Device device, std::ostream & err_log) {
        std::string src = ""
#include "float_defines.cl"
            + get_primary_kernels();
        std::vector<cl::Kernel> primary_kernels = get_kernels(src, context, device, err_log);
        src = ""
#include "float_defines.cl"
            + get_utility_kernels();
        std::vector<cl::Kernel> utility_kernels = get_kernels(src, context, device, err_log);
        src = ""
#include "float_defines.cl"
            + get_trigonometric_kernels();
        std::vector<cl::Kernel> trig_kernels = get_kernels(src, context, device, err_log);
        std::vector<cl::Kernel> final_kernels;
        final_kernels.insert(final_kernels.end(), primary_kernels.begin(), primary_kernels.end());
        final_kernels.insert(final_kernels.end(), utility_kernels.begin(), utility_kernels.end());
        final_kernels.insert(final_kernels.end(), trig_kernels.begin(), trig_kernels.end());
        return final_kernels;
    }
    static std::vector<cl::Kernel> get_double_kernels(cl::Context context, cl::Device device, std::ostream & err_log) {
        std::string src = ""
#include "double_defines.cl"
            + get_primary_kernels();
        std::vector<cl::Kernel> primary_kernels = get_kernels(src, context, device, err_log);
        src = ""
#include "double_defines.cl"
            + get_utility_kernels();
        std::vector<cl::Kernel> utility_kernels = get_kernels(src, context, device, err_log);
        src = ""
#include "double_defines.cl"
            + get_trigonometric_kernels();
        std::vector<cl::Kernel> trig_kernels = get_kernels(src, context, device, err_log);
        std::vector<cl::Kernel> final_kernels;
        final_kernels.insert(final_kernels.end(), primary_kernels.begin(), primary_kernels.end());
        final_kernels.insert(final_kernels.end(), utility_kernels.begin(), utility_kernels.end());
        final_kernels.insert(final_kernels.end(), trig_kernels.begin(), trig_kernels.end());
        return final_kernels;
    }
};
```

Kernel Testing.cpp (main)

```
#define CL_HPP_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#define CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#define CL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#include<CL\cl2.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<chrono>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<filesystem>

#include "TaskGenerator.hpp"

namespace filesystem = std::experimental::filesystem;

void print_device_info(std::ostream & out, cl::Platform platform, cl::Device device) {
    out << std::setw(20) << std::left << "Platform: " << platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>() << "\n";
    out << std::setw(20) << std::left << "Name: " << device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << "\n";
    out << std::setw(20) << std::left << "Memory Size: " << device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE>() << "\n";
    out << std::setw(20) << std::left << "Device Type: " << ((device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_TYPE>() == CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU) ? "GPU" : "CPU") << "\n";
}

void test_device(cl::Platform platform, cl::Device device, filesystem::path output_file_path) {
    std::ofstream out(output_file_path);
    print_device_info(out, platform, device);
    cl::Context context(device);
    cl::CommandQueue queue{ context, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE };
    size_t size = 100'000;
    buffers char_buffers = buffers::make_buffer<cl_char>(context, size);
    buffers short_buffers = buffers::make_buffer<cl_short>(context, size);
    buffers int_buffers = buffers::make_buffer<cl_int>(context, size);
    buffers long_buffers = buffers::make_buffer<cl_long>(context, size);
    buffers float_buffers = buffers::make_buffer<cl_float>(context, size);
    buffers double_buffers = buffers::make_buffer<cl_double>(context, size);
    auto char_kernels = kernel_generator::get_char_kernels(context, device, out);
    auto short_kernels = kernel_generator::get_short_kernels(context, device, out);
    auto int_kernels = kernel_generator::get_int_kernels(context, device, out);
    auto long_kernels = kernel_generator::get_long_kernels(context, device, out);
    auto float_kernels = kernel_generator::get_float_kernels(context, device, out);
    std::vector<cl::Kernel> double_kernels = kernel_generator::get_double_kernels(context, device, out);
    std::vector<task> tasks;
    for (auto & kernel : char_kernels) {
        tasks.emplace_back(queue, kernel, &char_buffers, "char");
    }
    for (auto & kernel : short_kernels) {
        tasks.emplace_back(queue, kernel, &short_buffers, "short");
    }
    for (auto & kernel : int_kernels) {
        tasks.emplace_back(queue, kernel, &int_buffers, "int");
    }
    for (auto & kernel : long_kernels) {
        tasks.emplace_back(queue, kernel, &long_buffers, "long");
    }
    for (auto & kernel : float_kernels) {
        tasks.emplace_back(queue, kernel, &float_buffers, "float");
    }
    for (auto & kernel : double_kernels) {
        tasks.emplace_back(queue, kernel, &double_buffers, "double");
    }

    std::vector<cl::Event> events;
    size_t index = 0;
    for (auto & task : tasks) {
        events.emplace_back(task.enqueue());
        std::cout << "Enqueueing " << task.get_kernel().getInfo<CL_KERNEL_FUNCTION_NAME>() << "(" << task.get_type_name() << ")" << "\n";
        cl::Event e = task.enqueue();
    }

    out << "==========================================\n\nProfiling Results:\n\n";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < events.size(); i++) {
        events[i].wait();
        auto duration = task::time_event(events[i]);
        std::cout << "Task " << (i + 1) << " of " << events.size() << " complete.\r";
        std::string task_name = tasks[i].get_kernel().getInfo<CL_KERNEL_FUNCTION_NAME>();
        task_name.append("(" + tasks[i].get_type_name() + ")");
        out << "    " << std::setw(40) << std::right << task_name;
        out << ": " << std::setw(12) << std::right << duration.count() << "ns\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
    int i = 0;
    for (auto & platform : platforms) {
        std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
        platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);
        for (auto & device : devices) {
            test_device(platform, device, "Device " + std::to_string(i++) + ".txt");
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

char_defines.cl, short_defines.cl, int_defines.cl, long_defines.cl, float_defines.cl, double_defines.cl

```
R"D(
typedef char Scalar;
typedef char2 Vector2;
typedef char4 Vector4;
typedef char8 Vector8;
typedef char16 Vector16;
)D"
//All the other defines files are identical, but with their respective types swapped in.
//Only exception is double_defines.cl, which also has '#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable' added.
```

Primary Transform.cl

```
R"D(
#define UNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a) a * a + a / a
#define BINARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b) a * b + a / b
#define TERNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b, c) a * b + c / a
)D"
```

Trigonometry Transform.cl

```
R"D(
#define UNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a) sin(a) + cos(a) + tan(a)
#define BINARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b) sin(a) + cos(b) + tan(a)
#define TERNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b, c) sin(a) + cos(b) + tan(c)
)D"
```

Utility Transform.cl

```
R"D(
#define UNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a) log(a) + hypot(a, a) + tgamma(a)
#define BINARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b) log(a) + hypot(b, a) + tgamma(b)
#define TERNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b, c) log(a) + hypot(b, c) + tgamma(a)
)D"
```

Transformations.cl

```
R"D(
Scalar Unary_Transform1(Scalar a) {
    return UNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a);
}

Vector2 Unary_Transform2(Vector2 a) {
    return UNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a);
}

Vector4 Unary_Transform4(Vector4 a) {
    return UNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a);
}

Vector8 Unary_Transform8(Vector8 a) {
    return UNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a);
}

Vector16 Unary_Transform16(Vector16 a) {
    return UNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a);
}

Scalar Binary_Transform1(Scalar a, Scalar b) {
    return BINARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b);
}

Vector2 Binary_Transform2(Vector2 a, Vector2 b) {
    return BINARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b);
}

Vector4 Binary_Transform4(Vector4 a, Vector4 b) {
    return BINARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b);
}

Vector8 Binary_Transform8(Vector8 a, Vector8 b) {
    return BINARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b);
}

Vector16 Binary_Transform16(Vector16 a, Vector16 b) {
    return BINARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b);
}

Scalar Ternary_Transform1(Scalar a, Scalar b, Scalar c) {
    return TERNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b, c);
}

Vector2 Ternary_Transform2(Vector2 a, Vector2 b, Vector2 c) {
    return TERNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b, c);
}

Vector4 Ternary_Transform4(Vector4 a, Vector4 b, Vector4 c) {
    return TERNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b, c);
}

Vector8 Ternary_Transform8(Vector8 a, Vector8 b, Vector8 c) {
    return TERNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b, c);
}

Vector16 Ternary_Transform16(Vector16 a, Vector16 b, Vector16 c) {
    return TERNARY_TRANSFORM_PROCESS(a, b, c);
}
)D"
```

Transform Kernels.cl

```
R"D(
kernel void unary_transform_scalar(global Scalar * a, global Scalar * output) {
    size_t id = get_global_id(0);
    output[id] = Unary_Transform1(a[id]);
}

kernel void binary_transform_scalar(global Scalar * a, global Scalar * b, global Scalar * output) {
    size_t id = get_global_id(0);
    output[id] = Binary_Transform1(a[id], b[id]);
}

kernel void ternary_transform_scalar(global Scalar * a, global Scalar * b, global Scalar * c, global Scalar * output) {
    size_t id = get_global_id(0);
    output[id] = Ternary_Transform1(a[id], b[id], c[id]);
}

kernel void unary_transform_vector2(global Vector2 * a, global Vector2 * output) {
    size_t id = get_global_id(0);
    output[id] = Unary_Transform2(a[id]);
}

kernel void binary_transform_vector2(global Vector2 * a, global Vector2 * b, global Vector2 * output) {
    size_t id = get_global_id(0);
    output[id] = Binary_Transform2(a[id], b[id]);
}

kernel void ternary_transform_vector2(global Vector2 * a, global Vector2 * b, global Vector2 * c, global Vector2 * output) {
    size_t id = get_global_id(0);
    output[id] = Ternary_Transform2(a[id], b[id], c[id]);
}

kernel void unary_transform_vector4(global Vector4 * a, global Vector4 * output) {
    size_t id = get_global_id(0);
    output[id] = Unary_Transform4(a[id]);
}
/* For the sake of brevity, I've cut the rest. It should be pretty clear what the
rest look like.*/

)D"
```

Comment: gpu is die shrink of hd4550 which has vliw type cores with fp optimized architecture(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360042/my-opencl-test-does-not-run-much-faster-than-cpu). also duplicate device listing comes from corrupt driver installations or non-uninstalled old drivers which can have flaws, also one of duplicates could be 64 bit version and other could be 32 bit you should check that and use the relevant one for your software. Also I've read somewhere that GCN was emulating integer division using FP32 calculations, so maybe you can do that if it is not happening in hd4000 series.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I'll do a more complete profile between the two devices to see what's going on there, but to be clear, the major performance differences are with the Intel CPU running on the Intel Platform vs the Intel CPU running on the AMD platform. The performance of the "two" Cedar devices is relatively normal.

Comment: I've read on one of "fanboy" posts on some review sites that intel forcing compilers to generate sub-obtimal instructions when there is "amd" in the system. But you are right, I see same thing when amd compiled on amd(I have fx8150, with compiled project on it), intel compiled on intel(same with c3060). 8 core performance of amd is bad compared to a 4 core intel and sometimes even weaker cpus like some 2 cores of new architecture. Compilers can have differencies with internal optimizations too.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware `AMD Radeon HD 5450` isn't a dual GPU and is probably listed twice because 2 different versions of AMD OpenCL platform are installed. I remember such a case when there was OpenCL 1.2 and experimental OpenCL 2.0. Check the platform versions.

When it comes to CPU I think `Experimental OpenCL 2.0 CPU Only Platform` is Intel implementation which is well optimized for Intel CPU. AMD OpenCL SDK is just made to work on Intel CPU and performance is poor - I was experiencing similar issue in the past.

To sum up - you don't have to use all available OpenCL platforms on all devices. Usually the latest OpenCL platform version for GPU gives decent performance and always use Intel OpenCL on Intel CPU.

Comment: The two AMD GPU listings have the same platform and OpenCL version. I'm working on adding some profiling information about them to see if I can find literally anything different between them aside from performance differences (the second seems to be like half as fast as the first). As to the more on-topic part: the program I'm writing is meant to query all available devices and determine, as objectively as possible, how fast they are. So I'm trying to work out if the AMD Platform/Intel Device combo "really is that slow", or if there's something I'm not doing that I should be doing.