# OpenCL Kernel timing measures 0 seconds or causes SIGABRT

Tags: c++, c, c++11, timer, opencl

I have problems measuring the time of a simple OpenCL kernel on Arch Linux (Manjaro). OpenCL's means to measure time give me an time of 0 seconds or give an error, depending on the conditions.

**My problem**

When executing a passthough kernel (basically `out[i] = in[i];`) on a big `NDRange`, the CPU measures the correct execution time, while OpenCL reports 0. Here is the console output:

```
CPU: 1.27449 s
GPU: 0 s
```

---

**passthrough.cpp** (excerpts)

```cpp
#include <CL/cl2.hpp>
#include "../Timer.hpp"

// start timer
Timer t;

// enqueue blocking
cl::Event processingEvent;
cl_int err = device->_queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(
        passthrough, // kernel
        cl::NullRange, // offset
        cl::NDRange(bufferSize), // global range
        {}, // local range
        nullptr, // wait for events
        &processingEvent // processing event
);
processingEvent.wait();

// measure time
double cpuUsec = t.deltaUsec();
double gpuUsec = Timer::deltaUsec(processingEvent);

// debug
cout << "CPU: " << cpuUsec / 1000000.0 << " s\n";
cout << "GPU: " << gpuUsec / 1000000.0 << " s\n";
```

**Timer.cpp** (excerpts)

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <ratio>
#include <CL/cl2.hpp>

Timer::Timer() {
    from = high_resolution_clock::now();
}

double Timer::deltaUsec() {
    return duration_cast<duration<double, std::ratio<1, 1000000>>>(high_resolution_clock::now() - from).count();
}

double Timer::deltaUsec(const cl::Event &event) {
    return (double) Timer::deltaNsec(event) / 1000.0;
}

// main function for the timing
unsigned long Timer::deltaNsec(const cl::Event &event) {
    auto end = event.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>();
    auto start = event.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>();
    return end - start;
}
```

---

**What I have tried**

1. I double checked the input values to be equal to the output - so the kernel actually works.
2. I deactivated compiler optimizations - just in case they cause the GPU to use the same buffer for in- and output values.
3. I added some logic so the code acutally needs more time to execute.
4. I checked in LLDB for the `start` and `end` variables in `Timer::deltaNsec()` not to be 0. They aren't and increase everytime I check.
5. After adding `#define CL_HPP_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS` before `#import cl2.hpp` I got the following SIGABRT error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cl::Error'
  what():  clGetEventProfileInfo
```

LLDB hinted me to the line `auto end = event.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>();` in `Timer.cpp` which I think is really confusing.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23074272/12657954) answer I used the timer correctly - did I?

---

**Some more info on my system / environment**

Used OpenCL driver (excerpts from custom YAML):

```
    NVIDIA CUDA:
      Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
      Version: OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 10.1.120
      Devices:
        GeForce GTX 1080 Ti:
          Timer resolution (ns): 1000
          Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          Version: OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
          Driver: 430.64
```

Installed packages

```
lib32-opencl-nvidia 1:430.40-1
opencl-headers 2:2.2.20170516-2
```

---

Maybe somebody had a similar problem and can help.

...and I hope I provided enough info - if not, please ask!

Comment: Try catching the exception and checking what the error code is

Comment: Good idea - got `OpenCL Error: CL_PROFILING_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE` now - looking into it now - thanks already!

Comment: Jup it worked! I added `CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE` to the `CommandQueue` options which solved my issue! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

[Alan Birtles's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604151/opencl-kernel-timing-measures-0-seconds-or-causes-sigabrt#comment105372505_59604151) helped me find the problem:

I surrounded the failing code with a `try-catch` block and printed the error code, which turned out to be `-7: CL_PROFILING_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE`.

**To be able to measure runtimes, you'll need to enable profiling on your `CommandQueue` like this:**

```cpp
auto queue = cl::CommandQueue(
        context,
        device,
        CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE
);
```

Thanks [Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5494370/alan-birtles)!